# Use Cognito User Pool Groups to Invoke a Lambda function without Federated Identities

Tags: javascript, browser, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am a newbie and feel I am missing a connection between the IAM Role on a Cognito User Pool Group and invoking a lambda function.

Use case:  I’d like to use Cognito to manage my user accounts without Federated Identities/Pools (I have no need for federation).  One of the features of Cognito is a concept of Groups, users can be segmented into different Groups with different associated IAM Roles all within the same pool (i.e. "admins" "customers" etc.).  Through a browser app and JavaScript (in S3) users login and get an accessToken (also an idToken and refreshToken).  To this point everything works great.

My problem is I want to call functions using 'lambda.invoke' for various things (i.e. read-write to DynamoDB) and hoped to avoid the extra step of using an API Gateway.

From [browser-invoke-lambda-function-example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/browser-invoke-lambda-function-example.html)  I can see how to do this using 'AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials', but from what I can tell this requires Federated Identities.

The  [Lambda class documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html) also documents how use an IAM accessKeyId and secretAccessKey, but I want to invoke the Lambda functions using the logged in User Credentials from the Cognito User Pool/Group->Role.

To be specific - **I would be greateful if someone could advise if it is possible to use lambda.invoke from a Browser JavaScript using just User Pools and User Groups** *(given there is an IAM role associated with the User Group)*?

If it is possible, please provide some sample code/or direction where I might find out how.

PS: I realise similar questions were posed before (i.e. [Is it possible to invoke a Lambda function with a cognito userpool identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619395/is-it-possible-to-invoke-a-lambda-function-with-a-cognito-userpool-identity)
) but the questions were thin on detail so the answers were equally vague.

Answer (score 1):

The following works if you enable an "Federated Identity Pools", use the "Cognito provider" only (as federated identities are not required), and under the provider "Authentication role selection" you select "Choose role from token" and "Role resolution" DENY.

```
function test() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    // Prepare to call Lambda function
    let pullResults;

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: <<IdentityPoolId>>,
      Logins: {
        "cognito-idp.<<REGION>>.amazonaws.com/<<USER POOL ID>>": <<idToken>>,
      },
    });

    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
      apiVersion: "2015-03-31",
    });

    const pullParams = {
      FunctionName: "<<Lambda Function Name>>",
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
      LogType: "None",
    };

    // Call the Lambda Function
    lambda.invoke(pullParams, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        pullResults = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
        console.log(pullResults);
      }
    });
  }
```

While this creates a Federated Identity, it does not use anything other than the Cognito Provider, and it takes the IAM Role from the Group the User belongs to.

Effectively:  Using Cognito Users from User Pools, and assigning permissions based on the User Group the user is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm calling Lambda from Browser-side JavaScript. If i remember correctly, you need to create  IAM role that allows your user's to access lambda. Works perfectly fine like this:

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

var params_lambda = {
  FunctionName: 'your_function_name',
  Payload: JSON.stringify(userPool.getCurrentUser().username) // data you want to send to lambda
};


lambda.invoke(params_lambda, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    window.location.href = "login.html";
  }
  else{
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.Payload)); // print out data you receive from lambda
  }
});
```

the instance `var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();` needs

> accessKeyId,
>
> sessionToken

and

> region

Comment: I hope this is not a silly question... @tipsfedor where do you get the accessKeyId from when only using User Pools?